# A little help for a script

Tags: linux, bash

I have made a script which downloads LibreOffice
and upgrades it on Slackware Linux.
I wanna do a simple correction; if a package file fails to download,
I want script to return "script fail at..."

For example,
if libreoffice-mozplug..etc fail script returns
"failed at upgradepkg --install-new libreoffice-mozplug..etc"
How to do it?

This is the script (I know..it is not the best but I'm working on it)

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
VERSION=4.3.1
LACKVERSION=14.1
alias wget="wget -nc"
#get!
wget http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/libreoffice/pkg64/$LACKVERSION/libreoffice-$VERSION-x86_64-1alien.txz.asc
wget http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/libreoffice/pkg64/$LACKVERSION/libreoffice-$VERSION-x86_64-1alien.txz
wget http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/libreoffice/pkg64/$LACKVERSION/libreoffice-dict-it-$VERSION-x86_64-1alien.txz.asc
wget http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/libreoffice/pkg64/$LACKVERSION/libreoffice-dict-it-$VERSION-x86_64-1alien.txz
wget http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/libreoffice/pkg64/$LACKVERSION/libreoffice-l10n-it-$VERSION-x86_64-1alien.txz.asc
wget http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/libreoffice/pkg64/$LACKVERSION/libreoffice-l10n-it-$VERSION-x86_64-1alien.txz
wget http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/libreoffice/pkg64/$LACKVERSION/libreoffice-mozplugin-$VERSION-x86_64-1alien.txz
wget http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/libreoffice/pkg64/$LACKVERSION/libreoffice-mozplugin-4.3.1-x86_64-1alien.txz.asc


#funzione gpg
funzion1()
{
arg1=$1
arg2=$2
gpg -v $1

}
#check gpg signature
for i in *.asc;do `funzion1 $i`;done

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "All is well"
else
    echo "Problem with signature."
fi


#funzione upgrade
funzion2()
{
arg1=$1
arg2=$2
upgradepkg --install-new  $1

}
#check upgrade
for i in *.txz;do `funzion2 $i`;done

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "All is well"
else
    echo "Problem with upgrade."
fi
```

Comment: Why ```do `funzion1 $i`;done``` and not ```do funzion1 "$i";done``` (without the backticks)?

Comment: Presumably, the 4.3.1 instead of $VERSION in the 'mozplugin' `.asc` file is accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you download the files, you just need the following (your function doesn't really do enough to bother defining it):

```
for i in *.asc; do
    if gpg -v "$i"; then
        echo "$i is OK"
    else
        echo "Problem with $i's signature"
    fi
done
```

You want to check the return status of each call to `gpg`, not just the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Change the:

```
for i in *.txz;do `funzion2 $i`;done
```

to

```
for i in *.txz;do `funzion2 $i || echo "Error with: $i"`;done
```

Ps: not tested.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but feel that the 8 invocations of `wget` are horribly repetitive.

Why not:

```
URL_BASE=http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/libreoffice/pkg64/$LACKVERSION
PKG_SUFFIX=$VERSION-x86_64-1alien.txz

for pkg in libreoffice libreoffice-dict-it libreoffice-l10n-it libreoffice-mozplugin
do
    main="$URL_BASE/$pkg-$PKG_SUFFIX"
    wget "$main" || exit 1
    wget "$main.asc" || exit 1
done
```